# codeblocks c++ stops working may be due to referencing

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, codeblocks

```
//in header file(in User class):
int howManyOpponents =0;
User** userArray; //(which is initialized to userArray = new User*[5] in the constructor)

//in class file:
void User::addWin(User* aUser)
{
    userArray[howManyOpponents] =aUser;
    howManyOpponents++;
}

//in main file
int maximumUser = 20;
User* userList[maximumUser];
(*userList[i]).addWin(userList[j]);
```

codeclocks stops working, I've traced the problem to the User::addWin and tried many different referencing or pointing settings but couldn't handle it. There may be a simple bug.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show what "stops working" means and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Unrelated: Global variables, used like this, in a C++ program? Why not use `std::vector` in stead of arrays ? Consider using RAII, smart pointers in stead of naked `new`.

Comment: Stop using raw pointers, all these problems go away

Answer (score 1):

```
User* userList[maximumUser];
```

Creates an array of `maximumUser` `User` pointers. No actual instances of `User` are constructed.

You then try to call a method with one of these uninitialised pointers, causing the crash:

```
(*userList[i]).addWin(userList[j]);
```

To fix, create an array of actual `User` instances (assuming `User`'s constructor does not require arguments):

```
User userList[maximumUser];
userList[i].addWin(userList[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing argument by reference instead of passing them by pointers. Try to avoid using raw poiters in your code. If you really need pointers, think about using smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example about how to use arrays of pointers:

```
    size_t maxUsers = 5;
    size_t maxUserLen = 48;
    char** UserList = 0;

    // First, allocates a array of pointers
    UserList = new char*[maxUsers];

    // Second, allocates each pointers in the array of pointers
    for(size_t i=0; i<maxUsers; i++)
    {
        UserList[i] = new char[maxUserLen];
        memset(UserList[i], 0, maxUserLen);
    }

    // Add user
    const char* user1 = "Mike";
    const char* user2 = "James";

    strcpy(UserList[0], user1); // First element in the list
    strcpy(UserList[1], user2); // Second element in the list, etc...
```